# Django Admin - get_form override

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to override get_form method in my admin.py. I wrote this code:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(InactiveSiteAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['category'].widget.can_add_related = False
    form.base_fields['subcategory'].widget.can_add_related = False
    form.base_fields['category1'].widget.can_add_related = False
    ...
    ...
    form.base_fields['category'].widget.can_change_related = False
    return form
```

Is it possible to override all fields in one line?:

```
form.base_fields[ALL_FIELDS].widget.can_add_related = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if looping over them works, with something like:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(InactiveSiteAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    for field in form.base_fields.keys():
        form.base_fields[field].widget.can_add_related = False
    return form
```